# Cannot install Pygame for Python 3.5.1

Tags: python3

I am trying to use Kivy 1.8.0 with Python 3.5.1 on my Ubuntu 15.04.
Kivy generates an Error:

> Fatal Error : Window no available :abort.

After some time I came to know it needs PyGame, but I cannot figure out how to find and Install PyGame for Python3.5.1.

I request a way out for the Following :

1. Installing pygame on Python3.5.1

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution on the [Pygame wiki](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu?parent=Compilation):

> ### Python 3.x
>
> ```sh
> #install dependencies
> sudo apt-get install mercurial python3-dev python3-setuptools python3-numpy python3-opengl libav-tools libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev libsdl1.2-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libtiff5-dev libx11-6 libx11-dev fluid-soundfont-gm timgm6mb-soundfont xfonts-base xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic fontconfig fonts-freefont-ttf
>
> # Grab source
> hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
>
> # Finally build and install
> cd pygame
> python3 setup.py build
> sudo python3 setup.py install
>
> # Run some tests
> python3 -m pygame.tests
> python3 -m pygame.examples/aacircle
> python3 -m pygame.examples/aliens
> python3 -m pygame.examples/freetype_misc
> python3 -m pygame.examples/glcube
> python3 -m pygame.examples/sound
> python3 -m pygame.examples/stars
> ```

You can also check installation by running `import pygame` in IDLE.

Comment: The above solution is missing at least two dependencies. You will also require python3-setuptools and libfreetype6-dev

Comment: This answer is halfway obsolete. Check the link in the answer for information updated to 16.04.